# How do I reuse Threads with different ExecutorService objects?

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

Is it possible to have one thread pool for my whole program so that the threads are reused, or do I need to make the ExecutorService global/ pass it to all objects using it.

To be more precise I have multiple tasks that run in my program but they do not run extremely often.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
```

I believe that it would be unnecessary to have a full thread running all the time for every single task but it might also be costly to restart the thread every single time when a task is executed.

Is there a better alternative to making the Thread pool global?

Comment: Are you sure you need threads? If the tasks are very simple, then do them in your thread.

Comment: The tasks need to be scheduled and run asynchronously. I do not think there is any alternative.

Comment: C# uses a global thread pool, while leaving programmers the possibility to create other pools. I'd say this is a good solution. If you need a global executor, just make a singleton factory, which will host your thread pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I reuse Threads with different ExecutorService objects?

It is not possible to re-use threads across different `ExecutorService` thread-pools.  You can certainly submit vastly different types of `Runnable` classes to a common thread-pool however.

> Is there a better alternative to making the Thread pool global?

I don't see a problem with a "global" thread-pool in your application.  Someone needs to know when to call `shutdown()` on it of course but that's the only problem I see with it.  If you have a lot of disparate classes which are submitting tasks, they all could access this set (or 1) of common background threads.

You may find however that different tasks may want to use a cached thread pool while others need a fixed sized pool so that multiple pools are still necessary.

> I believe that it would be unnecessary to have a full thread running all the time for every single task but it might also be costly to restart the thread every single time when a task is executed.

In general, unless you are forking tons and tons of threads, the relative cost of starting one up every so often is relatively small.  Unless you have evidence from a profiler or some other source, this may be premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 there is a new solution.
The fork join global thread pool:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--